# How can I create a Site Map for a Password Protected Site

Tags: microsoft-visio, sitemap

Microsoft Visio has a feature where it will create a site map for an existing website. However, my website has a login and users must be authenticated to view the content.

Is there any way to enter credentials into Visio or provide Visio with an authenticated session id so that it could create the site map?

Answer (score 2):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/map-protected-web-site-areas-HP001055666.aspx

For Web sites that use HTTP authentication:
On the Web Site Map menu, click Generate Site Map.Click Settings, and then click the Advanced tab.Under HTTP authentication, enter a valid name and password, click OK, and then click OK again.  The Web Site Map template regenerates the memory model and lays out your site map.

For Web sites that use some other kind of security:
On the drawing page, find the link to the Web page where some kind of interaction is required (such as clicking a link or entering a password).Right-click the link and click Interactive Hyperlink Selection.In the Interactive Discovery dialog box, interact with the Web page (for example, click a link or enter a password).  When the Interactive Discovery dialog box closes, the links you navigated to are added to the Web site map.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the authentication is implemented on the web site. If it uses basic HTTP authentication then you can enter the username and password into the Generate Site Map tool:

1. When you see the Generate Site Map dialog click Settings.
2. Click Advanced
3. Enter the password at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: It's a good answer, but my site unfortunately uses a login form which programatically checks the user's credentials against a database. From my understanding, HTTP authentication is handled by the webserver and is generally a static username/password combination (not db backed). So it won't work for my specific case.